# Make node tree with recursive table with Express and Mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, typescript, express, backend

I'm working in a REST api with ExpressJS and Mongo and I have a collection with N quantity of levels.

So to solve this problem I'm using an recursive table (or collection) in mongo where a field is the id and every register has a parent_id which is at the same level as it's childs.
To explain better this, here is an E-R representation

[image]

So as you se, mongo will save the data like this json (accounts level 0 has null parent)

```
[
  { "id": "45TYYU", "parent_id": null, "name":"account 1", "type": 1, "category": 1 },
  { "id": "45TYYXT", "parent_id": "45TYYU", "name":"account 2", "type": 1, "category": 1 },
  { "id": "45TYYPZ", "parent_id": "45TYYU", "name":"account 3", "type": 1, "category": 1 },
  { "id": "45TYYPZRE", "parent_id": "45TYYPZ", "name":"account 4", "type": 1, "category": 1 },
  { "id": "45TYYPZSX", "parent_id": "45TYYPZ", "name":"account 5", "type": 1, "category": 1 },
  { "id": "45TYYPZGP", "parent_id": "45TYYXT", "name":"account 6", "type": 1, "category": 1 }
]
```

account 2 and account 3 are children of account 1, while account 4 and account 5 are children of account tree and account 6 is child of account 2 ... but every register is at the same logical level only identifying through parent_id.

so I need to transform this data into a GET method to restructure it like this:

```
[
    { 
        "id": "45TYYU",
        "parent_id": null,
        "name":"account 1",
        "type": 1,
        "category": 1,
        "children": [
            { 
                "id": "45TYYXT",
                "parent_id": "45TYYU",
                "name":"account 2",
                "type": 1,
                "category": 1,
                "children": [
                    { "id": "45TYYPZGP", "parent_id": "45TYYXT", "name":"account 6", "type": 1, "category": 1 }
                ]
            },
            { 
                "id": "45TYYPZ",
                "parent_id": "45TYYU",
                "name":"account 3",
                "type": 1,
                "category": 1,
                "children": [
                    { "id": "45TYYPZRE", "parent_id": "45TYYPZ", "name":"account 4", "type": 1, "category": 1 },
                    { "id": "45TYYPZSX", "parent_id": "45TYYPZ", "name":"account 5", "type": 1, "category": 1 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        "id": "45TFJK",
        "parent_id": null,
        "name":"account 7",
        "type": 1,
        "category": 1,
        "children": [
            { 
                "id": "47HJJT",
                "parent_id": "45TFJK",
                "name":"account 8",
                "type": 1,
                "category": 1
            },
            { 
                "id": "47YHJU",
                "parent_id": "45TFJK",
                "name":"account 8",
                "type": 1,
                "category": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Yes... the parents level 0 has null parent_id and I want to put it's children inside an array called "children" and then send like this in the GET response to my UI

What is the best way to do this in expressJS?
Is there a library or component out there that allows me to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) and other useful array operators,

- `$match` filter that records only have `parent_id` is `null`
- `$graphLookup` to get child records and depth number in depthField `level`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `children` array and allow to not remove empty children
- `$sort` by depth level field `level` in descending order
- `$group` by `id` field and reconstruct `children` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { parent_id: null } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$id",
      connectFromField: "id",
      connectToField: "parent_id",
      depthField: "level",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$children",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "children.level": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      parent_id: { $first: "$parent_id" },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      type: { $first: "$type" },
      category: { $first: 1 },
      children: { $push: "$children" }
    }
  },
```

- `$addFields` now find the nested level children and allocate to its level,

  - $reduce to iterate loop of `children` array.
  - initialize default field `level` default value is -1, `presentChild` is [], `prevChild` is [] for the conditions purpose
  - `$let` to initialize fields:

    - `prev` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `prevChild` otherwise return `presentChild`
    - `current` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `presentChild` otherwise []
  - `in` to return `level` field and `prevChild` field from initialized fields

    - `presentChild` `$filter` `children` from `prev` array and return, merge current objects with `children` array using `$mergeObjects` and concat with `current` array of let using `$concatArrays`
- `$addFields` to return only `presentChild` array because we only required that processed array

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$children",
          initialValue: { level: -1, presentChild: [], prevChild: [] },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] },
                    "$$value.prevChild",
                    "$$value.presentChild"
                  ]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] }, "$$value.presentChild", []]
                }
              },
              in: {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevChild: "$$prev",
                presentChild: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            children: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: { $eq: ["$$e.parent_id", "$$this.id"] }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      id: "$_id",
      children: "$children.presentChild"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PkbIeZDrs92)

Answer (score -1):

@turivishal Im using same schema in backend nodejs im getting only show the
null object not for a parent child relation using same aggregration

```
    this.tickets.aggregate([
            {
              $match: {
                parent_id: null
              }
            },
            {
              $graphLookup: {
                from: "collection",
                startWith: "$id",
                connectFromField: "id",
                connectToField: "parent_id",
                depthField: "level",
                as: "children"
              }
            },
            {
              $unwind: {
                path: "$children",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
              }
            },
            {
              $sort: {
                "children.level": -1
              }
            },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: "$id",
                parent_id: {
                  $first: "$parent_id"
                },
                name: {
                  $first: "$name"
                },
                type: {
                  $first: "$type"
                },
                category: {
                  $first: 1
                },
                children: {
                  $push: "$children"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              $addFields: {
                children: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$children",
                    initialValue: {
                      level: -1,
                      presentChild: [],
                      prevChild: []
                    },
                    in: {
                      $let: {
                        vars: {
                          prev: {
                            $cond: [
                              {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$value.level",
                                  "$$this.level"
                                ]
                              },
                              "$$value.prevChild",
                              "$$value.presentChild"
                            ]
                          },
                          current: {
                            $cond: [
                              {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$value.level",
                                  "$$this.level"
                                ]
                              },
                              "$$value.presentChild",
                              []
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        in: {
                          level: "$$this.level",
                          prevChild: "$$prev",
                          presentChild: {
                            $concatArrays: [
                              "$$current",
                              [
                                {
                                  $mergeObjects: [
                                    "$$this",
                                    {
                                      children: {
                                        $filter: {
                                          input: "$$prev",
                                          as: "e",
                                          cond: {
                                            $eq: [
                                              "$$e.parent_id",
                                              "$$this.id"
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              $addFields: {
                children: "$children.presentChild"
              }
            }
          ]).then((result) => {
            
            console.log('test',result);
            
            // callback(result);

        }).catch((error) => {
            callback(error);
        });
```

output:

```
[
  {
    _id: '45TYYU',
    parent_id: null,
    name: 'account 1',
    type: 1,
    category: 1,
    children: []
  },
  {
    _id: '45TYYUA',
    parent_id: null,
    name: 'account 1',
    type: 1,
    category: 1,
    children: []
  }
]
```

Comment: SORRY BY MISTAKE COLLECTION NAME NOT MENTION IT QUERY