# Mongodb recursive query not working as expected with $graphLookup

Tags: mongodb

In my documents, I have the _id, a companyName and a sponsor (which identifies the parent document, by the _id).

For example, I have this first record which has no sponsor (parent)

```
_id:607536219910ef23e80e0bbe
companyname:"Main Company"
sponsor:"
```

Then Company 1, where the Main Company is the parent:

```
  _id:607e16760a9d2c16e06bc252
    companyname:"Company 1"
    sponsor:"607536219910ef23e80e0bbe"
```

And Company 2, where Company 1 is the parent:

```
_id:607e187b0a9d2c16e06bc253
companyname:"Company 2"
sponsor:"607e16760a9d2c16e06bc252"
```

And Company 3, where Company 2 is the parent:

```
_id:607e1f470a9d2c16e06bc254
companyname:"Company 3"
sponsor:"607e187b0a9d2c16e06bc253"
```

Im doing a $match to bring the children records for the main company

```
{
  sponsor: '607536219910ef23e80e0bbe'
}
```

And then I $addFields userid, which is a _Id converted to string. This is to match later with sponsor:

```
{"userid": { "$toString": "$_id" }}
```

Now, when I graphLookup I get the child company (Company 2) for Main Company, but I do not get Company 3 as a child of Company 2. I just get Company 1, and Company 2:

[image]

Here is my graphLookup

```
{
  from: 'pls',
  startWith: "$userid",
  connectFromField: 'userid',
  connectToField: 'sponsor',
  as: 'downline',
  maxDepth: 100,
  restrictSearchWithMatch: {}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

As Turivishal said below, the query works, but these are the result I expect:

```
[{
        "_id": "607536219910ef23e80e0bbe",
        "companyname": "Main Company",
        "downline": [{
            "_id": "607e16760a9d2c16e06bc252",
            "companyname": "Company 1",
            "sponsor": "607536219910ef23e80e0bbe",
            "downline": [{
                "_id": "607e187b0a9d2c16e06bc253",
                "companyname": "Company 2",
                "sponsor": "607e16760a9d2c16e06bc252",
                "downline": [{
                    "_id": "607e1f470a9d2c16e06bc254",
                    "companyname": "Company 3",
                    "sponsor": "607e187b0a9d2c16e06bc253"
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "sponsor": "",
        "userId": "607536219910ef23e80e0bbe"
    }
```

**SOLUTION BY TURIVISHAL:**

As per Turivishal solution, this is the final Pipeline that provides a PERFECT downline/hierarchy/tree view of the recurring query and works perfect with Angular Treeview controls. Thank you very much Turivishal. I believe you should post an answer so I can accept it and it can be useful for others.

His solution is quite similar to the one he proposed, but much better. I ended up creating a new field called PLID which duplicates the _id field, and it works amazingly well. I let the administrators decide if they believe this question should be closed, because again, Turivishal solution is based on that Q, but clearer in my opinion. Here is his work:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'sponsor': '0'
    }
  }, {
    '$graphLookup': {
      'from': 'pls', 
      'startWith': '$plid', 
      'connectFromField': 'plid', 
      'connectToField': 'sponsor', 
      'depthField': 'level', 
      'as': 'children'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$children', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'children.level': -1
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$plid', 
      'sponsor': {
        '$first': '$sponsor'
      }, 
      'companyname': {
        '$first': '$companyname'
      }, 
      'children': {
        '$push': '$children'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'children': {
        '$reduce': {
          'input': '$children', 
          'initialValue': {
            'level': -1, 
            'presentChild': [], 
            'prevChild': []
          }, 
          'in': {
            '$let': {
              'vars': {
                'prev': {
                  '$cond': [
                    {
                      '$eq': [
                        '$$value.level', '$$this.level'
                      ]
                    }, '$$value.prevChild', '$$value.presentChild'
                  ]
                }, 
                'current': {
                  '$cond': [
                    {
                      '$eq': [
                        '$$value.level', '$$this.level'
                      ]
                    }, '$$value.presentChild', []
                  ]
                }
              }, 
              'in': {
                'level': '$$this.level', 
                'prevChild': '$$prev', 
                'presentChild': {
                  '$concatArrays': [
                    '$$current', [
                      {
                        '$mergeObjects': [
                          '$$this', {
                            'children': {
                              '$filter': {
                                'input': '$$prev', 
                                'as': 'e', 
                                'cond': {
                                  '$eq': [
                                    '$$e.sponsor', '$$this.plid'
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'children': '$children.presentChild'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: are you sure its working perfectly see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EPa1YgZUPoy)

Comment: Hi Turivishal. Thanks for your reply. I saw the playground and that's what I get too, but Im looking for a tree view structure, where Company2 is located as an object at Company 1, and Company 3 is located as an object at Company 2, but not show up at the root level. I did this many times in SQL Server, but Im having a real issue to translate it to mongo db. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting... is there a reason why you are looking for that particular response?

Comment: Yes. A treeview that requires the json to be in that specific format :-(

Comment: I don't think is there any straight way to get this result see duplicate question and i have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139097/make-node-tree-with-recursive-table-with-express-and-mongo) with the solution and i have updated query as per your data [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KD0ZA-HT2wm), but you have to convert `sponsor` id to objectId otherwise this query will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make node tree with recursive table with Express and Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139097/make-node-tree-with-recursive-table-with-express-and-mongo)

Comment: That is amazing, Turivishal! I will give it a try right now. I was looking for an answer for hours over S.O and googling but I couldn't find that specific solution. thank you very much!

Comment: Your playground works perfect. I ended up creating a separate field for the ID and merging that with the Sponsor. I tried the solution you provided me from the other StackOverflow post, but it didn't work correctly. Your works like a charm. Thank you very much again, Turivishal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) and other useful array operators,

- `$match` filter that records only have `sponsor` is `""`
- `$graphLookup` to get child records and depth number in depthField `level`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `downline` array and allow to not remove empty children
- `$sort` by depth level field `level` in descending order
- `$group` by `id` field and reconstruct `downline` array
- `$addFields` now find the nested level children and allocate to its level,

  - `$reduce` to iterate loop of `downline` array.
  - initialize default field `level` default value is -1, `presentChild` is [], `prevChild` is [] for the conditions purpose
  - `$let` to initialize fields:

    - `prev` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `prevChild` otherwise return `presentChild`
    - `current` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `presentChild` otherwise []
  - `in` to return `level` field and `prevChild` field from initialized fields

    - `presentChild` `$filter` `downline` from `prev` array and return, merge current objects with `downline` array using `$mergeObjects` and concat with `current` array of let using `$concatArrays`
- `$addFields` to return only `presentChild` array because we only required that processed array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { sponsor: "" } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "sponsor",
      depthField: "level",
      as: "downline"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$downline",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "downline.level": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      sponsor: { $first: "$sponsor" },
      companyname: { $first: "$companyname" },
      downline: { $push: "$downline" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      downline: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$downline",
          initialValue: { level: -1, presentChild: [], prevChild: [] },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] }, "$$value.prevChild", "$$value.presentChild"]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] }, "$$value.presentChild", []]
                }
              },
              in: {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevChild: "$$prev",
                presentChild: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            downline: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: { $eq: ["$$e.sponsor", "$$this._id"] }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { downline: "$downline.presentChild" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S-U5hQYnGA2)