# How to transform MongoDB document to tree structure by Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document looks like as shown below and I want to transform it to a tree structure by id and parent using aggregation. Currently, I am using a tree transform function to create tree data. It becomes slower the speed depends on the number of documents. So, I want to create with aggregation. May I know, How can I implement it?

Thanks In Advance

```
 [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61275b0a85ba7b52a4d17ded"
  },
  "id": "b630-875e-2fab-78ff-fd9e",
  "value": "New Folder 1",
  "type": "rootfolder",
  "parent": 0,
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-26T09:12:42.751Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-26T09:12:42.751Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61285a4e85ba7b52a4d17e01"
  },
  "id": "0039-a4b3-5db9-dcd4-a75e",
  "value": "New Group 2",
  "type": "groupfolder",
  "parent": "b630-875e-2fab-78ff-fd9e",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-27T03:21:50.761Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-27T03:21:50.761Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129bdc530c5b1617073dbae"
  },
  "id": "0c51-53c5-bfe8-d6c7-9a4a",
  "value": "New Item",
  "type": "itemfolder",
  "parent": "0039-a4b3-5db9-dcd4-a75e",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T04:38:29.927Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T04:38:29.927Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129c55530c5b1617073dc97"
  },
  "id": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
  "value": "Pipes",
  "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
  "categoryName": "Pipes",
  "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
  "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "materialName": "Plastic",
  "type": "category",
  "parent": "0c51-53c5-bfe8-d6c7-9a4a",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129c55530c5b1617073dc99"
  },
  "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
  "categoryName": "Pipes",
  "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
  "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "materialName": "Plastic",
  "externalId": "b9a9d158-93f9-4fce-837f-e000eaa1a52a-00937ee2",
  "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
  "type": "element",
  "extracted": "0",
  "id": "37b0-63df-f62f-60ca-9bcd",
  "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129c55530c5b1617073dc9a"
  },
  "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
  "categoryName": "Pipes",
  "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
  "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "materialName": "Plastic",
  "externalId": "5b7d8e25-2d1b-454d-a361-a7463a931ac9-00939483",
  "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
  "type": "element",
  "extracted": "0",
  "id": "e528-4b3a-d2fc-1340-047c",
  "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129c55530c5b1617073dc9b"
  },
  "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
  "categoryName": "Pipes",
  "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
  "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "materialName": "Plastic",
  "externalId": "5b7d8e25-2d1b-454d-a361-a7463a931ac9-009395a8",
  "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
  "type": "element",
  "extracted": "0",
  "id": "88e1-45d1-740c-bce5-7c34",
  "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.899Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129c55530c5b1617073dc9c"
  },
  "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
  "categoryName": "Pipes",
  "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
  "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "materialName": "Plastic",
  "externalId": "e2c24341-812a-481c-860c-9e16a09e50a3-009396d4",
  "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
  "type": "element",
  "extracted": "0",
  "id": "3077-1c56-0fdd-ca33-a203",
  "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.900Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.900Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129c55530c5b1617073dc9d"
  },
  "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
  "categoryName": "Pipes",
  "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
  "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
  "materialName": "Plastic",
  "externalId": "453452c9-04d6-4b21-bfe6-c3a223c02e01-009397c1",
  "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
  "type": "element",
  "extracted": "0",
  "id": "d302-d200-f1c8-3252-f992",
  "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.900Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T05:10:45.900Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129ec3630c5b1617073dcc8"
  },
  "id": "3ded-02d5-f7f1-980a-069e",
  "value": "New Folder",
  "type": "rootfolder",
  "parent": 0,
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T07:56:38.210Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T07:56:38.210Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129ec3630c5b1617073dcc9"
  },
  "id": "1458-45eb-373e-0960-0374",
  "value": "New Folder 2",
  "type": "rootfolder",
  "parent": 0,
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T07:56:38.654Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T07:56:38.654Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6129ec3630c5b1617073dcca"
  },
  "id": "1b7b-9788-80e7-fbbe-889b",
  "value": "New Folder 3",
  "type": "rootfolder",
  "parent": 0,
  "updateBy": "admin",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T07:56:38.831Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-28T07:56:38.831Z"
  }
}]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "b630-875e-2fab-78ff-fd9e",
        "value": "New Folder 1",
        "type": "rootfolder",
        "parent": 0,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "0039-a4b3-5db9-dcd4-a75e",
                "value": "New Group 2",
                "type": "groupfolder",
                "parent": "b630-875e-2fab-78ff-fd9e",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "0c51-53c5-bfe8-d6c7-9a4a",
                        "value": "New Item",
                        "type": "itemfolder",
                        "parent": "0039-a4b3-5db9-dcd4-a75e",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "id": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154",
                                "value": "Pipes",
                                "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
                                "categoryName": "Pipes",
                                "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
                                "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                "materialName": "Plastic",
                                "type": "category",
                                "parent": "0c51-53c5-bfe8-d6c7-9a4a",
                                "data": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
                                        "categoryName": "Pipes",
                                        "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
                                        "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "materialName": "Plastic",
                                        "externalId": "b9a9d158-93f9-4fce-837f-e000eaa1a52a-00937ee2",
                                        "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
                                        "type": "element",
                                        "extracted": "0",
                                        "id": "37b0-63df-f62f-60ca-9bcd",
                                        "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
                                        "categoryName": "Pipes",
                                        "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
                                        "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "materialName": "Plastic",
                                        "externalId": "5b7d8e25-2d1b-454d-a361-a7463a931ac9-00939483",
                                        "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
                                        "type": "element",
                                        "extracted": "0",
                                        "id": "e528-4b3a-d2fc-1340-047c",
                                        "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
                                        "categoryName": "Pipes",
                                        "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
                                        "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "materialName": "Plastic",
                                        "externalId": "5b7d8e25-2d1b-454d-a361-a7463a931ac9-009395a8",
                                        "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
                                        "type": "element",
                                        "extracted": "0",
                                        "id": "88e1-45d1-740c-bce5-7c34",
                                        "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
                                        "categoryName": "Pipes",
                                        "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
                                        "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "materialName": "Plastic",
                                        "externalId": "e2c24341-812a-481c-860c-9e16a09e50a3-009396d4",
                                        "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
                                        "type": "element",
                                        "extracted": "0",
                                        "id": "3077-1c56-0fdd-ca33-a203",
                                        "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "Pipe Types_TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "modelName": "v91 : JTC_TSC_CS_RVT_2019_0001.rvt",
                                        "categoryName": "Pipes",
                                        "levelName": "INTERNAL DRIVEWAY / APRON LEVEL",
                                        "typeName": "TS_Drain Pipe 300mm Diameter",
                                        "materialName": "Plastic",
                                        "externalId": "453452c9-04d6-4b21-bfe6-c3a223c02e01-009397c1",
                                        "elevation": 360.49868766404285,
                                        "type": "element",
                                        "extracted": "0",
                                        "id": "d302-d200-f1c8-3252-f992",
                                        "parent": "53ff-4f29-9f95-bbba-c154"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3ded-02d5-f7f1-980a-069e",
        "value": "New Folder",
        "type": "rootfolder",
        "parent": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "1458-45eb-373e-0960-0374",
        "value": "New Folder 2",
        "type": "rootfolder",
        "parent": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "1b7b-9788-80e7-fbbe-889b",
        "value": "New Folder 3",
        "type": "rootfolder",
        "parent": 0
    }
]
```

The tree is like this :

[image]

Comment: see the similar question [Make node tree with recursive table with Express and Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139097/make-node-tree-with-recursive-table-with-express-and-mongo)

Comment: Hello @turivishal, Thanks for your reply, It is working properly. May I know, How to remove the fields(_id, createdAt, updatedAt, updateBy, level, and empty array data) at the output result. https://mongoplayground.net/p/oJCOq7-YJhs

Comment: you can use `$unset` or `$project` stage to remove 3 fields (_id, createdAt, updatedAt, updateBy) but it is hard to remove `level` and `data` fields see [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SnO2IWqaVLM)
i have added $unsert stage after lookup stage

Comment: thanks a lot, it is quite enough for me. 
This is worth more than a cup of coffee. I miss out to say something in there(I cannot find the edit option) because I am excited about your code. 
Thanks
Than Naing Oo

Comment: Take a look if my solution fits your requirements [https://mongoplayground.net/p/k25nXDnEJiL](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k25nXDnEJiL)

Comment: I got this error while I run with 41233 documents. It is not working even I set user allowDiskUse to true. Currently, I am using MongoDB Atlas M0 for testing. Is it related to this issue with M0. Do I need to upgrade to a dedicated M10? May I have a suggestion, pls?
(node:28484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Sort exceeded memory limit of 33554432 bytes, but did not opt in to external 
    at MessageStream.messageHandler

Comment: You need to open a new ticket

Comment: Yes, I posted a new ticket here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974231/mongodb-aggregate-error-mongoerror-bsonobj-size-20726581-0x13c4335-is-inval?noredirect=1#comment121901493_68974231