# MongoDB aggregate error (MongoError: BSONObj size: 20726581 (0x13C4335) is invalid.)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I got the below error while I execute the MongoDB aggregate function.
It is not working even I set user allowDiskUse to true. Currently, I am using MongoDB Atlas M10.
May I have a solution, pls?

MongoError: BSONObj size: 20726581 (0x13C4335) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: "ecba-d187-0635-84c1-db59"

The data info is like this:
COLLECTION SIZE: 21.45MB
TOTAL DOCUMENTS: 41051
INDEXES TOTAL SIZE: 560KB

I am using the code below.

```js
router.get("/load_agg", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.projectName) {
        var dbName = req.query.projectName;
        var appId = req.query.appId;
        var viewName = req.query.viewName;
        var model = ItemGroup(dbName, appId + "_" + viewName);
        await model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    parent: 0
                }
            },
            {
                $graphLookup: {
                    from: appId + "_" + viewName + "s",
                    startWith: "$id",
                    connectFromField: "id",
                    connectToField: "parent",
                    depthField: "level",
                    as: "data"
                }
            },
            {
                $unset: [
                    "data._id",
                    "data.createdAt",
                    "data.updatedAt",
                    "data.updateBy"
                ]
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$data",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    "data.level": -1
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$id",
                    parent: {
                        $first: "$parent"
                    },
                    value: {
                        $first: "$value"
                    },
                    type: {
                        $first: "$type"
                    },
                    data: {
                        $push: "$data"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    data: {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$data",
                            initialValue: {
                                level: -1,
                                presentData: [],
                                prevData: []
                            },
                            in: {
                                $let: {
                                    vars: {
                                        prev: {
                                            $cond: [
                                                {
                                                    $eq: [
                                                        "$$value.level",
                                                        "$$this.level"
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "$$value.prevData",
                                                "$$value.presentData"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        current: {
                                            $cond: [
                                                {
                                                    $eq: [
                                                        "$$value.level",
                                                        "$$this.level"
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "$$value.presentData",
                                                []
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    in: {
                                        level: "$$this.level",
                                        prevData: "$$prev",
                                        presentData: {
                                            $concatArrays: [
                                                "$$current",
                                                [
                                                    {
                                                        $mergeObjects: [
                                                            "$$this",
                                                            {
                                                                data: {
                                                                    $filter: {
                                                                        input: "$$prev",
                                                                        as: "e",
                                                                        cond: {
                                                                            $eq: [
                                                                                "$$e.parent",
                                                                                "$$this.id"
                                                                            ]
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    data: "$data.presentData"
                }
            }
        ]).allowDiskUse(true).then(data => {
            if (data) {               
                res.send({
                    code: 200,
                    message: "Successful!",
                    data: data
                });
            } else {
                res.send({ code: 500, message: "Invalid Info!" });
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);      // Failure
            res.send({ code: 500, message: "Data loading fail!" });
        });
    } else {
        res.send({ code: 500, message: "Invalid Info!" });
    }
});
```

Atlas Screen Shoot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFtzP.png

Comment: could you remove some stage from aggregate pipeline  ?and resend the query ?

Comment: each document should be < 16MB, probably you make somewhere a big array, and document gets so big (`allowdiskuse` is not related to document size)

Comment: each doc like this

{"_id":{"$oid":"612b99d9b48dfe5704f47ddc"},"value":"TS_CIS Beam_1100x250","modelName":"v58 : JTC_TSC_AR_RVT_2019_0001.rvt","categoryName":"Beams [CIS]","levelName":"1ST STOREY MEZZANINE","typeName":"1100x250","materialName":"TS_CIS Beam","externalId":"bb57a1a0-ddc7-480f-8f96-6ce188ff7a7d-04e06cdf","elevation":{"$numberDouble":"370.8989501312344"},"type":"element","extracted":"0","id":"9909-0f37-c99a-999b-2a83","parent":"f7cc-f04c-270f-d561-9905","updateBy":"admin","createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630247385415"}},"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630247385415"}}}

Comment: So, Is it not possible to use an aggregate function with the whole collection?

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text.

Comment: Do you have some sample data and expected output? Please edit your question instead of putting it as comment.

Comment: Do you need `$push: "$data"`? Otherwise try `$push: "$data.level"` or similar

Comment: This is my sample data and expected output. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963575/how-to-transform-mongodb-document-to-tree-structure-by-aggregation
It is working fine with 20000 documents. I got errors with  41051 documents.
The number of documents will be more and more.

Comment: how big is the returned document when you have 20000 documents?